# How to delete selected item from Firebase database?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm beginner in Firebase with android application, I succeed to display a `ListView` of places, now I want to delete a place  when I click on an item.

This is my attempt:

```
listPlace.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,final int position, long id) {

     final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EndroitActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete!");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Place p = list.get(position);
                System.out.println(p.getNomPlace());

                DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("place").child(p.getNomPlace());
                dR.removeValue();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fine, ya coward."
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        dialogBuilder.create().show();

        return true;
    }
});
```

[image: Database structure]

Comment: can you please share your database structure.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Have you to remove only `nomPlace` field?

Comment: @MehulKabaria, No, I want to delete the hole child

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query applesQuery = ref.child("place").orderByChild("nomPlace").equalTo(p.getNomPlace());
applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete entire node you have to do like below...

```
DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("place").child("autoKey");
                dR.removeValue();
dR. removeValue();
```

you have to replace `p.getNomPlace()` with your `autoKey`. it will remove the entire node from specific `autoKey`. `getUid()` can provide the autokey.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so, I should replace `.child("autoKey")` by `.child(getUid())`

Answer (score 0):

To remove a record from a Firebase database, you just need to use the `removeValue()` method directly on the reference. You don't need to use as listener at all. So to remove a particular place, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("place").child(placeId).removeValue();
```

In which `placeId` is the id of a particular place that you want to remove. Note, `placeId` is not the same with `getUid()` or user id. To get that id, you need to use `getKey()` method in the moment you generate that unique key using `push()` method like this:

```
String placeId = rootRef.child("place").push().getKey();
```

Having this `placeId`, you can use it in any `DatabaseReference`.