# How to delete selected item node from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code that I am trying for removing the particular node of data from the realtime database.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val place = mPlaces[position]

    holder.place.text = place.getPlace()

    holder.deletePlace.setOnClickListener {
        val currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val placeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val placeId = placeRef.child("UserPlaces").child(currentUserID).push().key
        if (placeId != null) {
            placeRef.child("UserPlaces").child(currentUserID).child(placeId).removeValue()
        }
    }
}
```

this is the snippet of the realtime database

```
  "UserPlaces": {
    "6yM7mtdJs1NPBCF3Je5hUpOA4h44": {
      "-NHMwCmm4-C2hBCdrbe2": {
        "place": "kjdlafaslfjlf",
        "placeType": "lsjaffaljs"
      }
    }
  },
```

I am unable to delete the data from realtime database. I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433654/how-to-delete-selected-item-from-firebase-database) link to solve the problem but I am unable to do it. Help me in solving this problem.

Comment: We can't see the values of the variables in your code (`currentUserID` and `placeId`), so we don't know which node it's actually trying to delete.  You're also not checking for errors anywhere, so we don't know if something is going wrong.  Please try hard coding the specific strings for the node you want to delete, and also check for errors then edit the question to share the results.

Comment: There are no errors in my code. So , if I want to delete a node that contains place as "kjdlafaslfjlf", how can I delete this node? What are the changes required in the code? In the reference link I have used the similar code shared by Alex Mamo.

Comment: I am getting null as error.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `push()` it generates a new unique ID, which won't exist in the database yet. So in this code, you generate such a new unique ID in `placeId` and then try to delete the non-existing node:

```
val placeId = placeRef.child("UserPlaces").child(currentUserID).push().key
if (placeId != null) {
    placeRef.child("UserPlaces").child(currentUserID).child(placeId).removeValue()
}
```

Since the node at `placeId` never exists, the call to `removeValue()` has no effect.

If you want to know an existing place, you'll need to **know** its key and pass that to the delete call. This can commonly be done because you read the data from the database to show it in your app and then kept the key in a variable/list (most common). Alternatively, you may know some other attribute of the node you want to delete, and can then [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to find the corresponding key.

If you don't know the key, nor have any way to determine it through a query, the only option is to delete all places for the user, which you'd do with:

```
placeRef.child("UserPlaces").child(currentUserID).removeValue()
```